# How can i download the files inside a folder on google cloud platform using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

```
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket([bucket_name])
blob = bucket.get_blob([path to the .txt file])
blob.download_to_filename([local path to the downloaded .txt file])
```

How can i adjust my python code to add something like `for filename in os.listdir(path):` to just copy all the files in a certain folder on there locally

Answer (score 5):

First of all, I think it is interesting to highlight that Google Cloud Storage uses a flat name space, and in fact the concept of "directories" does not exist, as there is no hierarchical file architecture being stored in GCS. More information about [how directories work](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork) can be found in the documentation, so it is a good read if you are interested in this topic.

That being said, you can use a script such as the one I share below, in order to download all files in a "folder" in GCS to the same folder in your local environment. Basically, the only important addition a part from your own code is that the [`bucket.list_blobs()` method](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/buckets.html#google.cloud.storage.bucket.Bucket.list_blobs) is being called, with the `prefix` field pointing to the folder name, in order to look for blobs which only match the folder-pattern in their name. Then, you iterate over them, discard the directory blob itself (which in GCS is just a blob with a name ending in `"/"`), and download the files.

```
from google.cloud import storage
import os

# Instantiate a CGS client
client=storage.Client()
bucket_name= "<YOUR_BUCKET_NAME>"

# The "folder" where the files you want to download are
folder="<YOUR_FOLDER_NAME>/"

# Create this folder locally
if not os.path.exists(folder):
    os.makedirs(folder)

# Retrieve all blobs with a prefix matching the folder
bucket=client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
blobs=list(bucket.list_blobs(prefix=folder))
for blob in blobs:
    if(not blob.name.endswith("/")):
        blob.download_to_filename(blob.name)
```