# Download multiple file from Google cloud storage using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to download multiple files from the Google cloud storage folder. I am able to download the single file but unable to download multiple files. I took this reference from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48944923/how-can-i-download-the-files-inside-a-folder-on-google-cloud-platform-using-pyth) but seems it is not working.
The code is as follow:

```
# [download multiple files]
bucket_name = 'bigquery-hive-load'
# The "folder" where the files you want to download are
folder="/projects/bigquery/download/shakespeare/"

# Create this folder locally
if not os.path.exists(folder):
    os.makedirs(folder)

# Retrieve all blobs with a prefix matching the folder
    bucket=storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    print(bucket)
    blobs=list(bucket.list_blobs(prefix=folder))
    print(blobs)
    for blob in blobs:
        if(not blob.name.endswith("/")):
            blob.download_to_filename(blob.name)

# [End download to multiple files]
```

Is there any way to download multiple files matching with the pattern(name) or something else. Since I am exporting the file from bigquery, the file names will be something like below:

```
shakespeare-000000000000.csv.gz
shakespeare-000000000001.csv.gz
shakespeare-000000000002.csv.gz
shakespeare-000000000003.csv.gz
```

Reference: Working code to download single file:

```
# [download to single files]

edgenode_destination_uri = '/projects/bigquery/download/shakespeare-000000000000.csv.gz'
bucket_name = 'bigquery-hive-load'
gcs_bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
blob = gcs_bucket.blob("shakespeare.csv.gz")
blob.download_to_filename(edgenode_destination_uri)
logging.info('Downloded {} to {}'.format(
    gcs_bucket, edgenode_destination_uri))

# [end download to single files]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After some trial, I solved this and couldn't stop myself from posting here as well.

```
bucket_name = 'mybucket'
folder='/projects/bigquery/download/shakespeare/'
delimiter='/'
file = 'shakespeare'

# Retrieve all blobs with a prefix matching the file.
bucket=storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
# List blobs iterate in folder 
blobs=bucket.list_blobs(prefix=file, delimiter=delimiter) # Excluding folder inside bucket
for blob in blobs:
   print(blob.name)
   destination_uri = '{}/{}'.format(folder, blob.name) 
   blob.download_to_filename(destination_uri)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may simply have the wrong level of indentation in your python code.  The block beginning with `# Retrieve all blobs with a prefix matching the folder` is within the scope of the `if` above so it's never executed if the folder already exists.

Try this:

```
# [download multiple files]
bucket_name = 'bigquery-hive-load'
# The "folder" where the files you want to download are
folder="/projects/bigquery/download/shakespeare/"

# Create this folder locally
if not os.path.exists(folder):
    os.makedirs(folder)

# Retrieve all blobs with a prefix matching the folder
bucket=storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
print(bucket)
blobs=list(bucket.list_blobs(prefix=folder))
print(blobs)
for blob in blobs:
    if(not blob.name.endswith("/")):
        blob.download_to_filename(blob.name)

# [End download to multiple files]
```

Comment: It has the same issue with this as well. when I print blobs it's returning empty `[]`