# How to access Google cloud storage bucket from c#

Tags: c#, .net, google-app-engine

We are trying to integrate Dynamics 365 FO with Google cloud storage. What happens is that there are no built in API to connect it to google cloud.

We are trying to use Google Cloud API in C# and then call c# in D365fo. I am stuck in Authentication step. I already created one class library project and added nuget package Google.Cloud.Storage.V1. How should I connect to OAuth2.0 to get access token to access google cloud?

How can we download bucket information in Google cloud to local folder using C#?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] of your progress so far.

Comment: I am microsoft Dynamics AX Technical Consultant.

Comment: We are trying to integrate Dynamics 365 FO with Google cloud storage.What happend is there are no built in API to connect to google cloud.So thats why we are trying to consume google cloud API in C# and then call c# in D365fo.I was stuck in Authentication itself.I created one class library project and added nuget package Google.Cloud.Storage.V1 then i how should i connect to Oauth2.0 to get access token to access google cloud.So please show some light on this

Answer (score 2):

Once you have installed and configured the SDK you can authenticate on google cloud from your workspace by:

1. Create a service account with project owner permissions
2. Download its .json key to your workspace
3. Save its path on an environment variable

[See this link](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started) for the detailed steps.

In the same link there is a [small script that verifies the authentication to your Google Cloud project](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#verifying_authentication).

Notice this line in that code:

```
var credential = GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault();
```

This line gets the credentials saved on your environment path (the key path you saved before) and uses it to authenticate to the project.

If you have done this you should be able to authenticate to your project and run the Google Cloud APIs.

Regarding your question, to list the files in a bucket you can check [this example](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/index.html#sample-code) in the API documentation, among other examples.

Comment: I need to move files from one bucket to another bucket.Please show some light on this.

Comment: how can i download all objects from buckets ? how to loop.

Comment: Please show some sample code how can i loop buckets in Google cloud to download all files.

Comment: You can see an example here (in python, but the idea is the same): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51203883/download-multiple-file-from-google-cloud-storage-using-python

Comment: How can i add files that are in buckets from google cloud  to memory stream

Comment: How can i add files that are in buckets from google cloud to memory stream

Comment: How can i add files that are in buckets from google cloud to memory stream

Comment: Experts Please provide some solution

Answer (score 0):

```
string _projectId = "YOUR-PROJECT-ID-GCP"; //ProjectID also present in the json file
GoogleCredential _credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("credential-cloud-file-123418c9e06c.json");

public IEnumerable<Google.Apis.Storage.v1.Data.Object> ListFiles(string bucketName)
{
    var storage = StorageClient.Create(_credential);
    var storageObjects = storage.ListObjects(bucketName);
    Console.WriteLine($"Files in bucket {bucketName}:");
    foreach (var storageObject in storageObjects)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(storageObject.Name);
    }

    return storageObjects;
}
```

You get the credentials json file from the google cloud portal where you create a bucket under your project..