# How to download files from GCS cloud bucket which has special characters in their file names using python client api?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-api-python-client

I am using Windows and I am able to download GCS files which don't have special characters.
I used the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51203883/download-multiple-file-from-google-cloud-storage-using-python) to download the files.
However, I am unable to download files which have special characters. (Pipe symbol)
Example filename: BRX_23022023|00000.csv

I have added the code. Files are downloaded as per the folder structure mentioned in the bucketname and foldername variables. However, if the filename has special characters, it simply creates the folder structure, but it won't download the files.  C:\adt-dev-outputs\archive\2023\02

```
import os
from google.cloud import storage
from os import makedirs

cred_json_file_path = 'C:/Users/config.json'
client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(cred_json_file_path)

def download_blob(bucket: storage.Bucket, remotefile: str, localpath: str='.'):
    """downloads from remotepath to localpath"""
    localrelativepath = '/'.join(remotefile.split('/')[:-1])
    totalpath = f'{localpath}/{localrelativepath}'
    filename = f'{localpath}/{remotefile}'
    makedirs(totalpath, exist_ok=True)
    print(f'Current file details:\n  remote file: {remotefile}\n  local file:  {filename}\n')
    blob = storage.Blob(remotefile, bucket)
    blob.download_to_filename(filename, client=client)


def download_blob_list(bucketname: str, bloblist: list, localpath: str='.'):
    """downloads a list of blobs to localpath"""
    bucket = storage.Bucket(client, name=bucketname)
    for blob in bloblist:
        download_blob(bucket, blob, localpath)


def list_blobs(bucketname: str, remotepath: str=None, filetypes: list=[]) -> list:
    """returns a list of blobs filtered by remotepath and filetypes
    remotepath and filetypes are optional"""
    result = []
    blobs = list(client.list_blobs(bucketname, prefix=remotepath))
    for blob in blobs:
        name = str(blob.name)
        # skip "folder" names
        if not name.endswith('/'):
            # do we need to filter file types?
            if len(filetypes) > 0:
                for filetype in filetypes:
                    if name.endswith(filetype):
                        result.append(name)
            else:
                result.append(name)
    return result


bucketname = 'adt-dev-outputs'
foldername = 'archive/2023/02'
filetypes = ['.csv'] # list of extentions to return
bloblist = list_blobs(bucketname, remotepath=foldername, filetypes=filetypes)

download_blob_list(bucketname, bloblist, localpath=bucketname)
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you can share us your code and the sample error message you've encountered when trying to download files which contains special characters.

Although, since you've mentioned that you're using Windows, it seems that some special characters including pipe or '|' is a [limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#naming-conventions) on naming convention.

Also, I found this [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/192496969) which might be related.